# What is a better way to stop this worker thread?

Tags: .net, multithreading, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I'm developing an application which periodically polls a web service for some data. The application has to run as a Windows service, thus it has to be started and stopped in an asynchronous way. I'm using threading for this.

The main loop of the worker thread acts this way:

```
bool stop = false;
int interval = 60000;    // 60 seconds, customizable

while(!stop)
{
    try
    {
        // Query the web service using a WebRequest
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        // Handle exception
    }

    // Process data

    try
    {
        Thread.Sleep(interval);
    }
    catch(ThreadInterruptedException)
    {}
}
```

To stop the worker thread, I do this from a controlling thread:

```
stop = true;
workerthread.Interrupt();
workerthread.Join();
```

This works perfectly... unless by chance the worker thread happens to be performing (or has yet to perform) a web request when `Thread.Interrupt()` is called; in this case, what gets actually interrupted is the web request (which presumably sleeps on its own), and the next `Sleep()` has to wait until its regular timeout to exit.

What is a better way to accomplish this and avoid interrupting the worker thread in the wrong place?

Comment: If all your service does is sleep and poll periodically then it should be a scheduled task rather than a service. See [Programs are not cats](http://blog.mischel.com/2013/02/01/programs-are-not-cats/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `MaualResetEvent`:

In the class that launches the thread:

```
ManualResetEvent evt = new ManualResetEvent(false);
```

Then modify your code to be:

```
int interval = 60000;    // 60 seconds, customizable

while(evt.WaitOne(interval))
{
    try
    {
        // Query the web service using a WebRequest
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        // Handle exception
    }

    // Process data
}
```

To stop the thread, just call `evt.Set();`

This will cause the thread to stop even even if it is in the middle of the 60 second wait.

Comment: What happens if the worker thread is not waiting yet when calling `evt.Set()`?

Comment: The next time it hits the top of the while loop it will stop immediately. Does each loop of your process take a long time?

Comment: No, at most a few seconds; it's ok to complete the running loop and exit when reaching the next WaitOne().

Comment: It works great, I've only moved the sleep at the bottom of the loop in order to have the first work cycle start immediately.

Comment: you can also actually WaitOne for 0 ms. When I need to do that I usually define a bool to track if it is the first loop and then do `WaitOne(isFirst?0:interval)`

Comment: `while(true)` and then `if(WaitOne(interval)) break;` works equally well :)